# Shopping Cart Rules for Mixed Products

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, shopping-cart-price-rules

How do I get items in the cart to apply discount if some product attributes are different, to explain. I have this rule set up for a 4 for £10 promo:

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
If total quantity  is  4  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions: 
Category  is  26
Bottle Size  is  10ml
VG/PG Mix  is  50/50

and this works if the items are all the same. However, these items have different flavour (attributes) and when we add say 2 of one flavour and 2 of another the discount does not apply. It's the same scenario with different child/single associated products. I've tried adding flavours etc. to the rule but this makes no difference to the outcome.

Has anyone experienced this and found a resolve or can someone tell me where I am going wrong please as this is driving me insane?

I'm using magento 1.9.3.8

Many many thanks